# Excel help: fomulas that reference the result of droplist choices and deduct from 6 different budgets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel 2013.

I need a budget sheet for 6 departments all on one sheet.
The columns are;

```
Date -- Amount -- Department (drop down lists) -- Finance Code -- Balance
```

I've put the data tables on sheet 2 containing the 6 Department Names, Finance Codes for them and budget amounts per department.

The resulting balance should be the 'Amount' minus the 'Departments' budget as a running total, for example:

```
01/01/2015 -- £24.50 -- Dept One -- 2112 -- £4975.50

02/01/2015 -- £98    -- Dept Two -- 2115 -- £4902

03/01/2015 -- £ 50  -- Dept One -- 2112 -- £4925.50
```

I've worked out how to automatically fill in the 'Finance Code' depending on 'Department' selected like this:

`=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!A2:B7,2,FALSE)`

but I can't get my head around an Array formula (I didn't even know what one was until yesterday!) that will use the resulting finance code on sheet 1 to lookup the department budget on sheet 2, running total it and input it back to the 'Balance' on only that line.

Then be able to handle a different Department and budget on the next line.

Yes I could just do 6 separate sheets but I want to learn something!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is going to be messy and I'm not taking the time to enter it into excel and error check it, so you might have to do a little troubleshooting, but something like this should get you started. 
Assuming that the budget is in column C on sheet 2.

```
=(VLOOKUP(D3,Sheet2!A2:C7,3,FALSE))-SUM(IF(A3:C3=D3,A2:C2,0))
```

That is going to recalculate the value each time so if there are a lot of rows it could take a little while